# Ajax and Jquery in Symfony

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, symfony

I'm a beginner in Symfony (version 2), I have a project achieved with plain basic PHP, and now I'm redoing my pages in dealing with Symfony framework, and arrived to my jquery ajax functions, surely, things gonna be different,
I used to do like this:

```
$("#div").click(function(){
  $.post("targetFile.php",{/*parameters*/,function(data){ });
});
```

Q: How to make that works on Symfony?
What to put instead of targetFile.php? a route most probably.
and what to do on the controller and router sides?
I looked out on Google and here, but didn't get any clear answers.
Regards.

Comment: what are you having problems with?

Comment: How to make a Jquery Ajax function works on Symfony?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you set inside routing.yml this:

```
_admin_ajax:
    resource: "@SomethingAdminBundle/Controller/AjaxController.php"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /admin/ajax
```

... and inside controller, that will handle ajax call this:

```
/**
 * @Route("/ajaxhandler", name="_admin_ajax_handler")
 */
public function handlerAction() {
    
    $isAjax = $this->get('Request')->isXMLHttpRequest();
    if ($isAjax) {
        //...
        return new Response('This is ajax response');
    }
    return new Response('This is not ajax!', 400);
}
```

... then inside for example TWIG template you should call it like this:

```
$("#div").click(function(){
  $.post("{{ url('_admin_items_add') }}",{/*parameters*/,function(data){ });
});
```

... and the real route for your action will be generated with templating engine.

Comment: Well, I'll try,but what if the template is a php file? what to put as a url.

Comment: Adding that solved the problem: `$isAjax = $this->get('Request')->isXMLHttpRequest();` really I don't understand Symfony logic :), any way, thank you, I appreciate your support bro.

Comment: And also clearing cache may affects, I can't say that it's the solution coz I was always clearing cache each time I change something.

Answer (score 5):

You realy just have to replace the targetFile.php by a custom route of yours.

So if you have this in your routing.yml:

```
# app/config/routing.yml
hello:
    pattern:      /ajax/target
    defaults:     { _controller: AcmeHelloBundle:Site:index }
```

You can use this javascript:

```
$("#div").click(function(){
  $.post("/ajax/target",{/*parameters*/,function(data){ });
});
```

On the Symfony2 side, the method indexAction of the SiteController of the AcmeHelloBundle will be called.

Comment: look what Firebug tells me: Not Found The requested URL /target was not found on this server. while my router is: `target: pattern: /target defaults: { _controller: WWBundle:Default:target}` and my Javascript is `$("#div").click(function(){ $.post("/target",{/*parameters*/,function(data){ }); });` and the controller is `public function targetAction(){ return $this->render('WWBundle:Default:target.html.php'); }` what's wrong Mr Damien?

Comment: Yes I did but still get this message: "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/target".

Comment: Adding that solved the problem: `$isAjax = $this->get('Request')->isXMLHttpRequest();` really I don't understand how Symfony wants to work :), any way, thank you, I appreciate your support.